# Include regex variable into another regex or combine regexes, plus names capture group

Tags: perl

I'm trying to include a stored regex pattern (`$portR`) into another.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
Getopt::Long::Configure("no_ignore_case");
my($host, $port);
my $getoptret = GetOptions(
    "H|host:s"          => sub { setHost($_[1]); },
    "p|port:i"          => \$port
);

#port: 0-65535  59999 64999 65499 65529 65535
#my $portPat= qr/[0-5][0-9]{,4}|6[0-4][0-9]{,3}|65[0-4][0-9]{,2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5]/;
#my $portR= qr/(((([0-5]?[0-9]?|6[0-4])[0-9]?|65[0-4])[0-9]?|655[0-2])[0-9]?|6553[0-5]?)/;
my $portR= qr/[0-9]/; #dummyRange
sub setHost{ #host: (https://)site.com(:port)
    if ($_[0] =~ /^(?<uriS>(?:https?):\/\/)?(?<hmain>(?<okC>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(\.(?&okC))+?)(?<hport>\:(${portR}))?$/) { 
        $host= $+{'uriS'}.$+{'hmain'};
        if ($+{'hport'}){ $port= substr($+{'hport'}, 1); }; print "|".$host.'|'.$port."\|\n";
    }else{
        printf "ERROR: no valid host: %s\n", $_[0];
    }
}
```

Returns:

> Use of uninitialized value $portR in regexp compilation at xyz.pl

In case the capture group was the issue, I tried:

```perl
if ($_[0] =~ /^(?<uriS>(?:https?):\/\/)?(?<hmain>(?<okC>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(\.(?&okC))+?)(${portR})?(?<hport>\:dummy)?$/)
```

but it still fails - but in the end I will still need that capture grouping as well.

Online all I find is only using a single regex variable.
How do I combine more than one or include it in another regex?

Comment: Use the URI module instead of writing your own (incorrect) regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the value of `$portR` **before** you call `GetOptions`.  Otherwise, the variable is undefined, resulting in the `Use of uninitialized value` warning.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
Getopt::Long::Configure("no_ignore_case");

my($host, $port);
my $portR = qr/[0-9]/; #dummyRange

my $getoptret = GetOptions(
    "H|host:s"          => sub { setHost($_[1]); },
    "p|port:i"          => \$port
);

sub setHost{ #host: (https://)site.com(:port)
    if ($_[0] =~ /^(?<uriS>(?:https?):\/\/)?(?<hmain>(?<okC>[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)(\.(?&okC))+?)(?<hport>\:(${portR}))?$/) { 
        $host= $+{'uriS'}.$+{'hmain'};
        if ($+{'hport'}){ $port= substr($+{'hport'}, 1); }; print "|".$host.'|'.$port."\|\n";
    }else{
        printf "ERROR: no valid host: %s\n", $_[0];
    }
}
```

I no longer get that warning when I call your script using `-host hostname`.